# Starting a second window in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to create a second window with a new activity class (like google docs or google calc).

Can somebody help me?

MyProduct

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Can you explain what is the second window or show a screenshot?

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow, when asking question please make sure you include all the necessary details so that your question is clear and to the point, this will give you fast and crisp answers from the community.